# '<function-style-cast>': cannot convert from 'cmdline_error' to 'boost::system::system_error'

Tags: c++, boost, type-conversion, boost-system

My project has been using boost 1.58 for ages. Now i have upgraded the visual studio version to 2017. And boost version 1.68.0

Boost 1.68.0 has some changes in its error_code class which breaks our build.

getting the following error

```
Error   C2440   '<function-style-cast>': cannot convert from 'cmdline_error' to 'boost::system::system_error'
```

where cmdline_error is defined as follows

```
enum cmdline_error
{
   success = 0,
   missing_argument,
   argument_conversion_failed
};
```

and this is the declaration which creates the error

```
cmdline_error cmdError;

boost::system::system_error systemError = boost::system::system_error(cmdError);
```

In linux build, the following error occurs

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘boost::system::system_error::system_error(cmdline_error)’
```

This code was working with boost 1.48, 1.58. 1.62

What is the correct way to handle this error here ?

Comment: `boost::system::system_error();` has constructor from `error_code`, but I do not see any constructor for `error_code` which would take a simple integral argument.

Comment: You can try `boost::system::system_error(boost::system::error_code(cmdError));`

Comment: the `error_code` constructor of `system_error` has now been (correctly) marked as explicit to prevent accidental conversion of numbers to `system_error`. What is your code trying to achieve? If you want to use custom error numbers you really need to define a new error category

Comment: @ThomasSablik that wont work either, `boost::system::error_code` isn't constructible from enums unless `is_error_code_enum` is specialised to true

Comment: @ThomasSablik You mean extend error_category and write my own error category with numbers ?

Comment: @ThomasSablik How to use the is_error_code_enum ? Is declaring some thing like template<> struct std::is_error_code_enum<X> : public std::true_type{}; would work ?

Comment: See the boost documentation for how to create your own error categories https://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.system#ex.system_03